# searching for a keyword in JSON having multiple fields

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

```
{
  "TaskType": "kkkk",
  "Status": "SUCCESS",
  "jobID": "18056",
  "DownloadFilePath": "https://abcd",
  "accountId": "1234",
  "customerId": "hhff"
}
```

This is sample data in message in notification table. I need to search for the keyword inside 3 or 4 fields out of 6 fields.
One way is to use multiple OR statements like:

```
SELECT message AS note 
FROM notification
WHERE message::jsonb->'TaskType' LIKE '%1234%' 
OR message::jsonb->'jobId' LIKE '%1234%' 
OR message::jsonb->'Status' LIKE '%1234%';
```

The results are satisfactory, but is there a way to optimize the query in case I need to search in more fields.

Comment: tag your database

Comment: Which database are you using? `mysql`, `sql server`, `postrgres`, `oracle`, `teradata`, `snowflake`, etc? JSON functions are very specific to the database product's sql dialect. I'm guessing this is postgres, in which case please add the `postgres` tag to your question to ensure you are attracting the postgres experts here on SO to get your question answered.

Answer (score 0):

you could just cast the message column to text and search inside the text:

```
SELECT message AS note 
FROM notification
WHERE message::text like '%1234%'
```

Comment: This will also find rows where `1234` is part of the key

Comment: hi,
thanx for the reply
I'm looking for the key in specific fields, not in entire JSON column

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through all key/value pairs:

```
select n.*
from notification n
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_each_text(n.message) as m(key,value)
              where key in ('TaskType', 'jobId', 'Status')
                and value like '%1234%');
```

If you want to search in all values, just leave out the `key in (..)` part in the sub-select.

Searching in all values can be done using a JSON path operator in Postgres 12 or later:

```
select *
from notification
where message @@ '$.* like_regex "1234"'
```

---

This assumes that `messages` is defined as `jsonb` - which it should be. If it's not, you need to cast it: `message::jsonb`